# Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider

Tags: windows, oracle, ora-12545

I get this error when trying to connect to a database server remotely using udl file:

> Test connection failed because of an
>   error in initializing provider.
>   ORA-12545: Connect failed because
>   target host or object does not exist

I believe it is not a connectivity problem, because I can do these checklists successfully:

- ping IP address

  - ping DNS name
  - tnsping service name
  - connect to the database using sqlplus, do select and other commands
    to the table
  - reconfigure service using Oracle Net Configuration Assistant

I also tried changing the host name in tnsnames.ora into its IP address, or put IP address and its alias name in etc\hosts, but it is still not working. I guess it is the problem in udl file. I use the same exact udl file with the one's in another PC that's working fine.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64bit client and what Oracle versions (server/client) are you using?

Comment: The client is 32 bit. Both server and client use Oracle version 10.2.0

Comment: The fact that it returns an `ORA` error code implies that it's using the driver as expected. As per another comment, perhaps it's not using the TNSNAMES you expect. I suggest renaming the TNSNAMES that you think it's using and retry and see if you get the same error (implying that it isn't using that one). Between ORACLE_HOME and 32/64 bit installs, it's easy to reference the wrong file

Answer (score 0):

First guess, wrong IP or wrong oracle home is being used (and thus different tnsnames.ora).
The other guess, I assume the UDL file is being used in a Windows-based PC : the error might be because the COM objects that being used as provider is not installed correctly. Maybe there is a problem with MDAC (Microsoft Data Access Components), you might also need to reinstall Oracle Client with Windows Interfaces enabled in custom options.

Comment: I tried to reinstall Oracle Client but it is still not working.

Comment: could you double click on the UDL file and see the Provider tab?